# How do i animate this rotation?

Tags: javascript

[This](https://github.com/sorccu/rotate.js/blob/master/Rotate.js) library rotates an image.

http://jsfiddle.net/PjDnu/

In the above example, it does rotate, but i want to animate it.
i use setInterval() , but it doesn't work:

```
window.onload = function(){
var elem = document.getElementById("im");
setInterval(function (){Rotate(elem, Math.PI/6)}, 1000/30);

}
```

Is there a chance to animate it? What is the right way to use this library?

Comment: i can wrap it with body tag, but it doesn't animate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PjDnu/10/**

The `<img>` element doesn't exist after executing `Rotate`. I've adjusted the code, so that the image keeps rotating. To accomplish this, I have made the following modifications:

- Created a container element after the original image - the original image has to be kept to dynamically calculate the new image.
- Added a counter in the scope of the interval (to keep track of the current/next angle)
- Added a third parameter (at the second position) to `Rotate`: This should be the container element, with an unique ID.

Answer (score 0):

Why you are using JS?
This will do it using CSS3 (which is much better) - http://jsfiddle.net/hUUYN/
The basic idea there is that you add the class 'spin2' to each image you wish to rotate...